# add condition to most recent values result

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregate

## mongoplayground

My result include 'mostRecentValues' and I wish to project values only if they are not the same. My struggle is in adding the condition to show only if there's a change between the 2 values (in this case mostRecentValues).

```
my_coll.create_index([('car_id',1),('timestamp',-1)], unique=True)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When an operation involves turning on an off full documents, think of **$group**. Adding this to your pipeline should point you in the right direction.

[(playground)](https://mongoplayground.net/p/BBF4PLNAcy6)

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$group": {
      _id: "cars",
      "cars": {
        "$push": {
          "$cond": [
            {
              "$ne": [
                {
                  "$arrayElemAt": [
                    "$mostRecentValues",
                    0
                  ]
                },
                {
                  "$arrayElemAt": [
                    "$mostRecentValues",
                    1
                  ]
                }
              ]
            },
            "$$ROOT",
            "$$REMOVE"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$cars"
  }
])
```

If you only have 3 fields on each document you could add:

```
  {
    $project: {
      car_id: "$cars.car_id",
      mostRecentTime: "$cars.mostRecentTime",
      mostRecentValues: "$cars.MostRecentValues"
    }
  }
```