# How to project all fields after modifying one in mongo

Tags: mongodb, aggregation

I am running a query in mongo that looks like this :

```
db.getCollection('roles').aggregate([
    {
        $project: {
            types: {$filter: { input: '$types', as: 'types',cond: {$eq: ['$$types.active', true]}}}
        },
    }
])
```

Where each document has several properties besides "types".
The problem I have now is that every object has only _id and types properties. All other properties I have to manually add them to the projection to get the entire object with all the properties plus the one I modified.

Is there any better way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Say the document is:

```
[
  {
    "_id": 1,
    title: "abc123",
    isbn: "0001122223334",
    author: {
      last: "zzz",
      first: "aaa"
    },
    copies: 5
  }
]
```

### Add one field and project all others automatically

Then use

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $addFields: {
      subtitle: "meow"
    }
  }
])
```

which is equivalent to the manual way

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      subtitle: "meow",
      title:1,
      // ...:1
    }
  }
])
```

### Adding a field and projecting some off

If you need to project some off, just add 2 stages:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $addFields: {
      subtitle: "meow"
    }
  }, {$project:{title:0}}
])
```

You can also project off with **$unset**

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $addFields: {
      subtitle: "meow"
    }
  }, {$project:["title", "isbn"]}
])
```

Comment: Worked like charm. Thanks

Comment: @Minsky based on your answer here, would you mind assisting my on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68199774/add-condition-to-most-recent-values-result) I have reason to believe that if I can change the name of the result array (mostRecentValues) to name fields - I can (perhaps) solve the problem. Thanks

Comment: Yes, give me a second @ProcolHarum

Comment: thanks it surely did the trick. very kind of you.